# Passing a string to Messenger Bot from a link

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Facebook Messenger allows us to deeplink to Messenger bots and track the referrer which is pretty useful, having read through the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params) on this I'm left wondering if it is also possible to send a text string to the bot via this method.

i.e a link that opens up the bot in Messenger and sends a text based message just as if the user had typed it themselves.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: Would prepopulating the text box suffice? FB does not allow your apps to act directly on behalf of users, but I think you can prepopulate and let the user send it themselves.

Comment: @JonChurch That might be a good enough alternative, thanks! Are you able to point me in the direction of documentation on the implementation of this?

Comment: I am combing the docs now, will let you know what I find. I work with chatbots everyday, and recall seeing something hidden in the API for this

Comment: I havent found anything that indicates this is possible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @JonChurch No worries,from what I can see, and from lack of documented evidence, I don't think this is yet possible. Thanks for checking back in, your effort is very much appreciated.